# Search audio file for pattern?

Tags: audio, search, music

I want to split a very large audio file at certain points. At certain points a radio announcer comes on and says something like “deux radio” and it always sounds exactly the same (it’s a recorded clip). How can I find that bit of repeated audio through out the entire MP3? It would be nice if I could split at that point, but even if it spits out the times, I can split it with another program.

Comment: I have the same problem and it's super annoying. I can see the waveform in front of me in audacity and it's the same each time. In theory it should be possible but I can't find any tool to do it. I'm going to investigate the audiogrep suggestion and post back.

Answer (score 3):

In theory—you’ll have to write your own app to do this—you would need to do this:

1. Run the WAV file through a speech recognition engine [Sphinx Speech Recognition](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/) is a free open source engine.
2. Have your speech recognition engine spit out text in real-time in memory and also keep track of the sample length location. Everytime the string “deux radio” is found, spit out the sample location to a `splitlog.txt` file. Since this is in realtime you get an approximation of the sample location.
3. Write your own wav splitter app: Gather all the sample location points from `splitlog.txt` and split the WAV accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called [audiogrep](http://antiboredom.github.io/audiogrep/) which transcribes text using speech-to-text conversion and then creates audiocuts based on text searches.

I haven't seen any option to output time stamps instead of audio clips, you probably need to modify the source slightly to that (or contact the author and ask him). I also don't know how well it will handle French (or whatever language your announcer uses).

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

- [TAPESTREA](http://taps.cs.princeton.edu/): Experimental software which is described as:

  > TAPESTREA (or taps) is a unified framework for interactively
  >   analyzing, transforming and synthesizing complex sounds. Given one or
  >   more recordings, it provides well-defined means to:
  >
  > - identify points of interest in the sound and extract them into reusable - templates
  > - transform sound components independently of the background and/or other events
  > - continually resynthesize the background texture in a perceptually convincing manner
  > - controllably place event templates over backgrounds, using a novel - graphical user interface and/or scripts written in the ChucK audio
  >     programming language
- [Voice Converter](http://www.voiceconverter.net/): Shareware ($29.95, trial version with no time limit) which is described as a tool that can be a:

  > Pitch Editor, Formant Shift, Vibrato, Raspiness, Breathiness, Pitch
  >   Range Scaling, Pitch Smoothing, Time Stretching…

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) for that purpose. Audacity can remove static, hiss, hum, or other constant background noises. You can also cut, copy, paste and delete within tracks easily. Check the full [features list](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features) out for more info.

Comment: Can it automatically search for the pattern? I think not.

Comment: I’m sure there are some plugins that can.

Answer (score -1):

You *should be able to* use Audacity as Mehper said. To do it, you can select the audio you want to remove and create a “Noise Profile” (do this from the Remove Noise option in the effects area) from it, then select the whole track and use the “Remove Noise” feature.